# Scalac behavior - useless scans?

Tags: java, scala, compiler-construction, compilation

In "Programming in scala" book by Martin Odersky, it explained the reason why `scalac` seems slow (page 114):

> The reason is that every time the compiler starts up, it spends time
>   scanning the contents of jar files and doing other initial work before
>   it even looks at the fresh source files you submit to it.

What is the compilation benefit from scanning jar files everytime any compilation is started?
Indeed, if most of developers use FSC (Fast Scala compiler) to avoid this default behavior, why haven't scala's authors removed these scans?

Why doesn't `javac` behave similarly?

Comment: I hope most developers use zinc (incremental scala compiler, which is build into sbt, recent versions of maven plugin and some other tools).

Comment: I said FSC since it's the one precised in the book. I've just started learning Scala so I've wondered why `javac` doesn't need a compiler deamon as scala optimized compilation process seems to need.

Comment: I suspect javac would be faster if it had a compiler daemon.  Java is a simpler language than most and the compiler does very little in the way of optimization, which has some advantages. ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey Faster because as being a daemon, Java Runtime would be run once, the first time compiler is launched instead of during every compilation?

Comment: @Mik378 I believe that is why, but I don't have any proof it would be significantly faster.

Comment: The first thing that I would look at when comparing the two is that `scalac` is implemented in Java while `javac` is a native binary (so it doesn't really need to scan any jar files in order to launch itself). AFAIK, FSC performs the initialization also, but the main difference is that it doesn't exit after a compilation, but waits for other jobs to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because `scalac` simply calls a class in a `.jar` file. My guess is that they do not want to create temporary (or cache) files.